# ¿Cómo crear un formulario web multi-step con barra de progreso?

Tags: javascript, html, web, formularios, webforms

Necesito crear un formulario multi-step con barra de progreso. Es la primera vez que lo intento, como aún no tengo conocimientos avanzados primero estoy haciendo pruebas antes de implementarlo en mi web.

Ya creé los códigos de html y JavaScript, pero al probar no me funciona la interactividad del formulario y la consola no me muestra ningun error.

No sé qué paso esté olvidando o qué parte del código haya realizado mal, ¿pueden ayudarme por favor?

Aquí están los códigos...

```js
<!-- Obtenemos el formulario y los pasos -->
const form = document.querySelector("#multi-step-form");
const steps = form.querySelectorAll(".step");

<!-- Obtenemos los botones para avanzar y retroceder -->
const nextButtons = form.querySelectorAll(".next-step");
const previousButtons = form.querySelectorAll(".previous-step");

<!-- Inicializamos la barra de progreso -->
const progressBar = form.querySelector(".progress");
progressBar.style.width = `${(1 / steps.length) * 100}%`;

let currentStep = 0;

<!-- Función para mostrar el paso actual y ocultar los demás -->
function showStep(stepIndex) {
  <!-- Ocultamos todos los pasos -->
  steps.forEach((step) => {
    step.style.display = "none";
  });

  <!-- Mostramos el paso actual -->
  steps[stepIndex].style.display = "block";

  <!-- Actualizamos la barra de progreso -->
  progressBar.style.width = `${((stepIndex + 1) / steps.length) * 100}%`;
  currentStep = stepIndex;
}

<!-- Función para avanzar al siguiente paso -->
function nextStep() {
  showStep(currentStep + 1);
}

<!-- Función para regresar al paso anterior -->
function previousStep() {
  showStep(currentStep - 1);
}

<!-- Eventos para los botones de avanzar y retroceder -->
nextButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", nextStep);
});

previousButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", previousStep);
});

<!-- Mostramos el primer paso al cargar la página -->
showStep(0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulario de Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="multi-step-form">
        <div class="step">
          <h2>Paso 1</h2>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" />
          <button class="next-step">Siguiente</button>
        </div>
      
        <div class="step">
          <h2>Paso 2</h2>
          <input type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad" />
          <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" />
          <button class="previous-step">Anterior</button>
          <button class="next-step">Siguiente</button>
        </div>
      
        <div class="step">
          <h2>Paso 3</h2>
          <input type="text" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" />
          <button class="previous-step">Anterior</button>
          <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
      
        <div class="progress-bar">
          <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    <script src="./multi-step-form.js"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Mi idea es probarlos primeramente, ya que como mencioné al principio aún no tengo conocimientos avanzados, y luego llevarlo a mi sitio web, que está construido con WordPress y el formulario que tengo actualmente es con el plugin Contact Form 7.

Answer (score 2):

Debes omitir el comportamiento que trae por defecto el `button` cuando está dentro de un `form`, lo lograrías con `preventDefault()`.

Entonces, a estos listeners:

```
nextButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", nextStep);
});

previousButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", previousStep);
});
```

Debes agregarle el evento del botón como parámetro y evitar el evento que tiene por defecto el botón (que lo que hacía era refrescar la página), y posteriormente ejecutas tus funciones, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
nextButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    nextStep();
  });
});

previousButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    previousStep();
  });
});
```

También recuerda que los comentarios en JS es con `//` o `/**/`, mientras que no con `<!-- -->`.

---

**Código:**

```js
// Obtenemos el formulario y los pasos
const form = document.querySelector("#multi-step-form");
const steps = form.querySelectorAll(".step");

// Obtenemos los botones para avanzar y retroceder
const nextButtons = form.querySelectorAll(".next-step");
const previousButtons = form.querySelectorAll(".previous-step");

// Inicializamos la barra de progreso
const progressBar = form.querySelector(".progress");
progressBar.style.width = `${(1 / steps.length) * 100}%`;

let currentStep = 0;

// Función para mostrar el paso actual y ocultar los demás
function showStep(stepIndex) {
  // Ocultamos todos los pasos
  steps.forEach((step) => {
    step.style.display = "none";
  });

  // Mostramos el paso actual
  steps[stepIndex].style.display = "block";

  // Actualizamos la barra de progreso
  progressBar.style.width = `${((stepIndex + 1) / steps.length) * 100}%`;
  currentStep = stepIndex;
}

// Función para avanzar al siguiente paso
function nextStep() {
  showStep(currentStep + 1);
}

// Función para regresar al paso anterior
function previousStep() {
  showStep(currentStep - 1);
}

// Eventos para los botones de avanzar y retroceder
nextButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    nextStep();
  });
});

previousButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    previousStep();
  });
});

// Mostramos el primer paso al cargar la página
showStep(0);
```

```html
<form id="multi-step-form">
  <div class="step">
    <h2>Paso 1</h2>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" />
    <button class="next-step">Siguiente</button>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <h2>Paso 2</h2>
    <input type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad" />
    <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" />
    <button class="previous-step">Anterior</button>
    <button class="next-step">Siguiente</button>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <h2>Paso 3</h2>
    <input type="text" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" />
    <button class="previous-step">Anterior</button>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```